# Find Ancestor of an Attribute using Xpath

Tags: xpath, libxml2

```
<?xml>
<env>
<body>
<folderxml>
<folder id='1'>
 <folder id='2' name ='document'>
   <folder id='3' name ='Music'>
     <folder id= '4' name= 'album' xlink='true'>
     </folder>
   </folder>
</folder>
</folder>
</folderxml>
</body>
</env>
```

I need the path if the attribute 'link' is true. Something like xpath.evaluate(path if(link=true)). The result should be something like "/documents/music/album"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the following XPath expression (based on [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)):

```
xmlXPathEval("//*[@xlink='true']", doc)
```

you obtain a link to the node list. In the example it is a single node `folder` with `id` `4`. Then you need to write a function that will travell all the parents and concatenate their `name` attributes.

If you needed only the name of the matching folder, than you could go with

```
xmlXPathEval("string(//*[@xlink='true']/@name)", doc)
```

and read the `stringval` member of the result. But that matches only the first node.

Edit: As for the function to iterate over parents I thought of direct access through `xmlNodePtr->parent` member and reading attributes with `xmlGetProp`. But as I see your comment (and also the title of the question) I think that you could make use of relative xpath queries, see [What's the most efficient way to do recursive XPath queries using libxml2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1683081/772981).

Comment: xpath.evaluate("//*[@link='true']/@name", xlink); then i do recursive to get the parent by adding /../ till the selected name.    xpath.evaluate("//*[@link='true']/../@name", link); and then i append the values

Comment: Good suggestion, I needed to correct the second part of the answer. I added also another notice.